# Sum an array of Func<double, double> objects

Tags: c#, vector, sum, lambda, integral

I am programming a method to obtain the result of an integral of a function of two variables, above one of the variables. The result is therefore a function of the other variable. I am using a numerical method to construct the result in intervals, for each one of that I store in a position of a vector of the type `Func<double, double>`. I want to sum up all the positions in the vector, and I don´t know how can i implement the Sum method of the vector of `Func<double,double>` to reach that.

Anyone can help me? We need something like obtain m:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<double, double>[] l = new Func<double, double>[2] {(x) => x, (x) => x +1};

        Func<double, double> m = l.Sum<>...;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Can you provide an actual worked example of the math?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Func<double, double>[] l = new Func<double, double>[2] {(x) => x, (x) => x + 1};

Func<double, double> m = x => l.Sum(f => f(x));
```

For example, `m(5)` → `l[0](5) + l[1](5)` → `(5) + (5 + 1)` → `11`.